# How to call a function using multiple lines in php?

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

```
$db->store($arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5, \
           $arg6,$arg7,$arg8,$arg9,$arg10, \
           $arg11,$arg12,$arg13,$arg14,$arg15)
```

But that doesn't work, how would I go about doing this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the slashes. PHP ignores EOLs (end-of-line).

```
$db->store($arg1,$arg2,$arg3,$arg4,$arg5, 
           $arg6,$arg7,$arg8,$arg9,$arg10, 
           $arg11,$arg12,$arg13,$arg14,$arg15)
;
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need the `\`, since PHP ignores all whitespace characters in your source code (except for the ones in strings of course). Just leave it out.

Comment: Haha ... well that was fast ... and a tie by the looks of things, votes for both, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the slashes, or in fact, anything at all.

You do need to end with a semi-colon though, which you've missed out.

Comment: Just forgot to put in the question.